# Vue 3 include local static files into index.html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli-3, webpack-loader, webpack-html-loader

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
```

I have a basic Vue 3 project and within my `public/index.html` file I want to include files from root directory (e.g. `node_modules` or my `semantic` folder)

I've tried various configurations within `vue.config.js` file but seems like none of them works.

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '',
}
```

What's the proper way of including custom local css/js files into `index.hmtl` without moving them directly into `public` directory?

Answer (score 0):

I was with a similar problem a time ago, I asked here too but I found the solution myself, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326397/error-trying-to-get-local-images-in-vue-files-with-my-own-webpack-config), how I was using my own webpack configuration, it may differ from what you need to do, but I think the core is the same, the esModule option on file-loader was messing with the path of local files I wanted to load.